# Rewrite url with query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need a bit of help with this one. I want to strip the query from an url and rewrite the remaining part.

This is the current url

```
http://www.example.com/catold/catname/page/7?gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc
```

and want to rewrite it to

```
http://www.example.com/catnew/catname/page/1
```

Thanks

Comment: How does `7?gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc` relate to `1`? Does the query string simply get removed no matter what it is? Does `7` turn into `1`?

Comment: I want to remove /page/1 but edit I made was rejected by the ones who know best, and see the confusion.
I want to redirect it to http://www.example.com/catnew/catname. Page 7 doesn't exist and I don't use that query anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^catnew/catname/page/[0-9]+/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc [L,R]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use str.split("?")... it will split string by ? and you get strings array and

```
var str = "http://www.example.com/catold/catname/page/7?gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc";
var stringArry = str.split("?");
//  stringArray[0]  will be the string what you want...
```